# Move to section after click in HTML

Tags: html

This is my `ul list` in my Website. I would like it to be moved to the section on the same page when pressed on the href. (autoscroll to section)

```
<ul class="page-header__nav">
<li>
<a href="MOVE_TO_work" class="false">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="MOVE_TO_contact-form" class="false">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is my section:

```
<section class="work">...</section>
<section class="contact-form">...</section>
```

Comment: nothing, because I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are reffering to is called a "Jump link"

```
<ul class="page-header__nav">
<li>
<a href="#work" class="false">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#contact-form" class="false">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
<section class="work" id="work">...</section>
<section class="contact-form" id="contact-form">...</section>
```

Comment: did not work. the link#name is added but not scrolling

Comment: @Fsp1337 instead of name use id.. id="work" for work section element.

Comment: Roland is correct, this must be a browser compatibility thing. https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511